# Group R dataframe by chronological sequence for different events

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that can be simplified to this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  Subject = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102),
  event = c('A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'),
  trialtype = c("immneg", "rneg", "immneg", "rneg", "rneg", "immneg", "rneg", "immneg"),
  timing = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

I hope to create a new column called `ref1` that tracks for each `Subject` and each `event`, whether `immneg` or `rneg` comes first in `trialtype` (based on the `timing` column). The value of `ref1` should be `1` if `rneg` comes first and `0` if `immneg` comes first.

This is the desired solution:

```
solution <- data.frame(
  Subject = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102),
  event = c('A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'),
  trialtype = c("immneg", "rneg", "immneg", "rneg", "rneg", "immneg", "rneg", "immneg"),
  timing = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
  ref1 = c(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I matched your `solution` df by grouping on `Subject` and `Event` and then doing a mutate by going off of the `first` row in each group

```
library(dplyr)
example %>%
  group_by(Subject,event) %>%
  mutate(ref1=ifelse(first(trialtype) == 'rneg',1,0))
```

Answer (score 2):

A dubious base R approach

```
example$num = seq_len(nrow(example))
X = lapply(split(example, list(example$Subject, example$event)), 
           \(x) transform(x[order(x$timing), ], ref1 = ifelse(trialtype[[1]] == "rneg", 1, 0))) |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _) 
X = X[order(X$num), ] |> `row.names<-`(NULL)  
X$num = NULL

> X
  Subject event trialtype timing ref1
1     101     A    immneg      1    0
2     101     B      rneg      2    1
3     101     B    immneg      3    1
4     101     A      rneg      4    0
5     102     A      rneg      5    1
6     102     B    immneg      6    0
7     102     B      rneg      7    0
8     102     A    immneg      8    1
```

A similar solution, missing the obvious:

```r
Y = by(example[c("trialtype", "timing", "num")], example[c("Subject", "event")], 
       FUN = \(x) transform(x[order(x$timing), ], ref1 = ifelse(trialtype[[1]] == "rneg", 1, 0))) |>
  array2DF() |>
  ( \(.) .[order(.$num), ] )() |>
  transform(num = NULL) |>
  `row.names<-`(NULL)
```